# Chromebook fails to mount ext4 USB drive with valid FS

Tags: mount, chromebook

On my Chromebook, I followed [these steps](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/How-To-Install-To-External-Drive) to make an ext4 partition on a USB drive. Once the process was completed, when the the USB drive is plugged back in, Chromebook detects the drive and mounts it. No problems there.

If I were to mount the USB drive on a Linux host, `touch` a new file or something, eject and then plug back into the Chrome book, I get the popup saying the media is not recognized. If I were to mount manually from crosh/shell, I get the following error:

```
mount: /media/removable/foo: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

This is puzzling because the drive is not corrupted at all as I can still mount/read/write same drive on the a Linux host.

Essentially, Chromebook refuses to mount an FS that was used--and is still usable--elsewhere. What could be going wrong here? How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the Linux host (later kernel) modifies the journalling features to contain `journal_64bit journal_checksum_v3` which Chromebook (older kernel) is not happy about. The Chromebook kernel quite possibly is missing [this fix](https://github.com/endlessm/linux-meson/commit/68e74e922aaec81c2315b4a480c95abc7caee365).

Thanks to [LQ](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/sharing-ext4-file-system-between-cromebook-and-linux-4175644828/) for pointers.